# checking if an array rank is not equal to an int C#

Tags: unity, c#, inventory

I'm creating an inventory system for a dungeon crawler, I've got world gen, and player controls down, and this is the only snag.`

```
public Transform[] items;

public bool[] usingitem;

public int usingitemnumber;

public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
    {
        usingitemnumber = 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("2"))
    {
        usingitemnumber = 2;
    }


    if (Input.GetKeyDown("3"))
    {
        usingitemnumber = 3;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("4"))
    {
        usingitemnumber = 4;
    }

    usingitem[usingitemnumber] = true;
    if (usingitem.Rank != usingitemnumber)
    {
        usingitem[!= usingitemnumber] = false;
    }




}
```

`

i need to check if a rank on the `transform[] usingitem` array is not equal to the `int usingitemnumber` , and if it's not equal to it set it to false, and keep the on that is equal to it true

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

- `usingitem` is an array of bools
- `usingitemnumber` is the index of the item that should be active / in use
- You want the `i`th entry of `usingitem` to be `true` if and only if `i` is equal to `usingitemnumber` (ie. this array item corresponds to the currently used item)
- All other entries in the `usingitem` array should be `false`

We can do this very simply with a `for` loop. This steps over each entry in the array in order, from index `i = 0` to index `i = usingitem.Length - 1`, and sets it to `true` if the index `i` matches `usingitemnumber`, otherwise it assigns the array entry to `false`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < usingitem.Length; i++)
   usingitem[i] = (i == usingitemnumber);
```

Comment: thank you this is helpful, but I'm still new to how c# works how would this set the unused bools to false?,and how would i do that?

Comment: `i == usingitemnumber` is an expression using the equality comparison operator `==`. Before assigning a result to the array, the program evaluates "is the current index `i` equal to `usingitemnumber`?" If so, the expression evaluates to `true` and we store `true` in that array slot. Otherwise, the expression evaluates to `false` and we store `false` in that array slot. But in general, for basic language syntax like this, GameDev.StackExchange is not the best place to ask. Instead, work your way through beginner tutorials and guides for your language until you have a sound grasp of the basics.

Comment: ok, thank you for the help, i will continue with tutorials for now.